# "Connection reset by peer" and "Too many open files" exceptions wile trying to scale out Vert.x server

Tags: macos, websocket, netty, scalability, vert.x

I am trying to test the scalability of a Java Vert.x webserver (which is based on Netty) on Mac OS X. For that, I have increased the connection limit to 1 million:

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=1000200
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=1000100
sudo ulimit -n 1000000
```

Then I have created localhost aliases with:

```
for i in `seq 200 250`; do sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 172.16.123.$i ; done
```

I am now able to connect to these IP addresses; however, after around 1000-2000 established connections I get "Connection reset by peer" connections:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:712)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:191)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:228)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:447)
```

They are followed by "Too many open files" exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:393)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:386)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.<init>(SocketChannelImpl.java:104)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openSocketChannel(SelectorProviderImpl.java:60)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:145)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.newSocket(NioSocketChannel.java:48)
```

Interestingly, when I list all connections with netstat then I see that there are a lot of connections in the FIN_WAIT_1 state:

```
tcp4       0    213  172.16.123.230.55618   172.16.123.230.8877    FIN_WAIT_1 
tcp4       0    213  172.16.123.229.55624   172.16.123.229.8877    FIN_WAIT_1 
tcp4       0    213  172.16.123.228.55617   172.16.123.228.8877    FIN_WAIT_1 
tcp4       0    213  172.16.123.227.55616   172.16.123.227.8877    FIN_WAIT_1 
tcp4       0    213  172.16.123.226.55612   172.16.123.226.8877    FIN_WAIT_1
```

Other results:

```
$ netstat -a | wc -l:
14282
$ lsof | wc -l
6922
```

Server code (simplified):

```
HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
server.websocketHandler(ws -> {
    connections++;
    ws.exceptionHandler(t -> t.printStackTrace());
    ws.closeHandler(h -> {
        connections--;
    });

    if (ws.path().equals("/app")) {
        ws.dataHandler(data -> {
            // ...
        });
    } else {
        ws.reject();
    }
}).listen(8877);
```

Client code (simplified):

```
Handler<Void> connectHandler = new Handler<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Void e) {
        HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient().setHost(nextHost()).setPort(8877);

        client.connectWebsocket("/app", ws -> {
            connections++;
            ws.exceptionHandler(t -> t.printStackTrace());
            ws.closeHandler(h -> {
                connections--;
            });

            // ...
        });

        if (connections < 1000000) {
            vertx.runOnContext(this);
        }
    }
};
connectHandler.handle(null);
```

Both started with (on the same computer):

```
vertx run Class -cp classes:... -instances 8
```

Does anybody have an idea what could be the problem? I am not yet experienced with such setups and maybe I have just made a simple mistake. It doesn't help to increase the accept backlog.

Further information:

- http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/maximum-files-in-mac-os-x/
- [Virtual network interface in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87442/virtual-network-interface-in-mac-os-x)

**Update:**

After adding

```
limit maxfiles 1000100 2000200
```

to /etc/launchd.conf and

```
kern.maxfiles=2000400
kern.maxfilesperproc=1000200
```

to /etc/sysctl.conf and restarting the computer, it has gotten already a little bit better. However, after I while I get now "Too many open files" exceptions even for reading normal files although there are not more than 10000 open files:

```
Caused by: sun.nio.fs.UnixException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.getcwd(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.<init>(UnixFileSystem.java:67)
        at sun.nio.fs.BsdFileSystem.<init>(BsdFileSystem.java:41)
        at sun.nio.fs.MacOSXFileSystem.<init>(MacOSXFileSystem.java:44)
        at sun.nio.fs.MacOSXFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(MacOSXFileSystemProvider.java:45)
        at sun.nio.fs.MacOSXFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(MacOSXFileSystemProvider.java:38)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.<init>(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:56)
        at sun.nio.fs.BsdFileSystemProvider.<init>(BsdFileSystemProvider.java:36)
        at sun.nio.fs.MacOSXFileSystemProvider.<init>(MacOSXFileSystemProvider.java:40)
```

**Update 2**:

I have tried several other options as well but it seems like there is a limit at exactly 10180 connections which cannot be exceeded. Unless somebody has another idea, I will probably just switch to linux.

**Update 3**:

After adding the JVM option "-XX:-MaxFDLimit" I can now open 16331 connections until I get the following exceptions:

```
java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:435)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:427)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:643)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:176)
```

This is probably because of the default portrange (16383 ports):

```
net.inet.ip.portrange.first: 49152
net.inet.ip.portrange.last: 65535
```

However, since I use 50 localhost alises I would have expected to be able to open up to 16383 * 50 = 819150 connections. Or is it a known limitation that you cannot use the same port for different aliases?

**Update 4**:

I have tried to create virtual interfaces with networksetup but the result is the same:

```
for i in `seq 200 250`; do sudo networksetup -createnetworkservice lo$i lo0 ; sudo networksetup -setmanual lo$i 172.16.123.$i 255.240.0.0 ; done
```

Comment: Maybe you run out of available `Ephemeral Ports`?

Comment: @swKK I don't think so since it doesn't matter whether I connect to only localhost or to all of the 50 aliases. Also, the portrange contains 16383 ports. Anyway, I will increase it and check if it makes any difference.

Comment: @swKK Unfortunately, it hasn't helped to increase the ephemeral port range.

Comment: 10180 simultaneous connections is a lot for a typical application/machine to handle. Are you sure you need to keep all of those connections open? For 1M+ simultaneous connections you'd usually start using some combination of application-optimized TCP stacks and/or load-balancing hardware/DNS with multiple servers.

Comment: Netty has no problem with 10k connections, even with default settings.

Comment: I fear that the JVM does not support SO_REUSEPORT...

Comment: On Ubuntu I have been able to open more than 60k connections. So either the problem above is an OSX or OSX JVM limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your JVM options:

`-XX:- MaxFDLimit` per https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/Java_VMOptionsRef/Articles/JavaVirtualMachineOptions.html

Originally answered here:
[Java file limit on OSX lower than in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451343/java-file-limit-on-osx-lower-than-in-bash)

Comment: Thank you very much for this tip! I can now open 16331 connections and then I get "java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address" exceptions. This is probably due to the ephemeral port range limit (currently 16383), but I do not really understand why because I use 50 aliases to circumvent that. I will update the question.